# Orthogonal solution of matrix equation $ {\bf X} {\bf A} {\bf X}^\top = {\bf B} $

Tags: matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations, orthogonal-matrices, similar-matrices

Given symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices $\bf A$ and $\bf B$, define the following matrix equation in ${\bf X} \in \mathrm{O}(n)$.

$$ {\bf X} {\bf A} {\bf X}^\top = {\bf B},$$

Given any SPD matrices ${\bf A}, {\bf B}$, does there exist an orthogonal solution ${\bf X}$? If ${\bf X} \in \mathrm{O}(n)$ exists, does it have a closed form expression? When ${\bf X}$ is confined within SPD matrices, I know this is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation).  So how about when ${\bf X} \in \mathrm{O}(n)$?

Comment: Do $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: They might have. The solution is not required to be unique.

Comment: If the don't have the same eigenvalues there is no solution.

Comment: why? Could you please give me some references?

Comment: Do you know what is the concept of similar matrices?

Comment: Thanks. I got your point. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric real $n\times n$ matrices. The following statements are equivalent:

1. There exists $X\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $XAX^{-1}=B$.
2. There exists $X\in\mathrm{O}(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $XAX^{T}=XAX^{-1}=B$.
3. $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues counting multiplicities.
4. $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

This follows from the spectral theorem.