# Solving $ {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} = {\bf X}^\top {\bf A}^\top {\bf A} {\bf X} $ for $\bf A$

Tags: matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations

Given fat full row rank matrices ${\bf X}, {\bf Y} \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$, where $m<n$, how to solve the following quadratic matrix equation in ${\bf A} \in \Bbb R^{m \times m}$?

$$ {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} = {\bf X}^\top {\bf A}^\top {\bf A} {\bf X} $$

Comment: @BenjaminWang I don't get it.  What about the cross terms?

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3326534/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325733/339790)

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3331628/339790)

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4699256/339790)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} = {\bf X}^\top {\bf A}^\top {\bf A} {\bf X} $$

Since $\bf X$ is rank-$m$, the matrix $\bf X X^\top$ is invertible. Thus,

$$ \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} {\bf X} {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} {\bf X}^\top \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} =  {\bf A}^\top {\bf A} $$

Hence, one solution can be found via the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of $ \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} {\bf X} {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} {\bf X}^\top \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} $, i.e.,

$$ \hat {\bf A} := \operatorname{Cholesky} \left( \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} {\bf X} {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} {\bf X}^\top \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} \right) $$

Plugging into the original matrix equation,

$$ {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} = {\bf X}^\top {\hat {\bf A}}^\top {\hat {\bf A}} \, {\bf X} = {\bf X}^\top \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} {\bf X} {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} \underbrace{{\bf X}^\top \left( {\bf X} {\bf X}^\top \right)^{-1} {\bf X}}_{=: {\bf P}} = {\bf P} \, {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} {\bf P} $$

where $\bf P$ is the $n \times n$ [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) that projects onto the $n$-dimensional row space of $\bf X$.  Thus, I am tempted to conclude that the original matrix equation has a solution if $ {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} = {\bf P} \, {\bf Y}^\top {\bf Y} {\bf P}$.  This is the case if the rows of $\bf Y$ are in the row space of $\bf X$.

Comment: in Matlab, use [`chol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html)

Comment: Hi @RodrigodeAzevedo, I have doubts about this solution. If you plug $\bf A^T \bf A$ back into the original equation, you don't recover $\bf Y^T \bf Y$.

Comment: @TomBennett Are you acquainted with least-squares?

Comment: Yes. If you plug $\bf A^T \bf A$ back in, you get something like $\bf X^T (\bf  X \bf X^T) ^{-1} \bf X \bf  Y^T \bf Y\bf  X^T (\bf X \bf  X^T)^{-1}X$ and they don't cancel out to ${\bf Y^T\bf  Y}$

Comment: @TomBennett I updated my answer.  Do you agree?

Comment: @TomBennett I did **not** claim that it is true in general.  I claimed that it is true if, say, the rows of  are in the row space of 

Comment: I see it now. The rows are projected onto the same subspace they are already in. Thanks!

Comment: @TomBennett This reminds me of the [normal equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html)

Comment: Absolutely. Let me see if it is possible to remove this assumption.

Comment: I have thought about this more. Fit looks like if $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$ don’t span the same row space, there can’t be a solution.